# What is appropriate data type for nvarchar, bit of MYSQL database to in HIVE?

Tags: mysql, hive, type-conversion, impala

I need to ingest data from mysql database to Hadoop by creating hive/impala tables. I have nvarchar and bit data types in mysql, so what is most appropriate data types in HIVE/Impala to declare while crating hive table. i am thinking of using string?

Comment: string / int ( 0, 1 )

Comment: + mike. Thanks for quick reply. but bit operator holds 0, 1 and NULL right. have you ever handled same any time?

Comment: tinyint(1) in mysql and  we use sqoop to export to hive. with jdbc parameter : tinyInt1isBit=false , data in hive table will be 0,1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string` and `tinyint` types in Hive/Impala. both allows nulls.